# When running cli.php it hangs and never completes

Tags: cron, cli

Running Cli.php was working with command line as well as though cron.  However it now just hangs and uses cpu but never completed.   Schedule jobs do run and execute  if used execute now on the admin page.  Any help would be appreciated.